# Selenium ide: already logged in or not?

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm working with Selenium Ide 2.9.1.

The problem is to check if, beginning the automatic process, the user has already logged in.

So, on the first page of www.pageexample.com I need to check if id=welcome is JOHN SMITH.

If yes, the user has already logged in and then it's possible to go on with the following instruction (clickandwait | id=button10).

If not (I mean id=welcome is not present in the page), the login is needed (and in this case I've already built the instuctions).

I've installed Selenium IDE: flow control.

Comment: Are you running into a certain problem to write this code? We're not here to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from the suggestion, I've elaborate the following code that seems to work:

storeElementPresent | id=loginbutton | x

storeElementPresent | id=sitename | y

gotoIf | x=y | z

....... operations of log in .......

label | z |

*loginbutton* is present only if the users has not logged in, *sitename* is always present (therefore always true): so, comparing the two values, in case of correspondence Selenium proceeds with the operation of log in, otherwise jumps to label z.

I know, it's an escamotage that can surely be improuved.